# Is installing juypter notebook with Homebrew is better than installing with pip?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I am new to python. And I want to install Juypter Notebook in my machine. I tried with installing Juypter Notebook with Homebrew. And also installed pip with Homebrew. But I was not able to import the package install in pip from Juypter Notebook.